# Is there a way to send keyboard key press to iframe content?

Tags: javascript

My iframe content responds to key press, is there a way to send key press into the iframe from the page which contains the iframe?

By the way, the usual way to simulate key press does not work in the scenario:

```
var ev = $.Event('keypress');
ev.which = 68;
ev.ctrlKey = true;
$('#frame').trigger(ev);
```

Comment: i am sure you are aware of [Cross Frame Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Frame_Scripting)

Comment: Thank you. Now I see that it is a security concern. You have the right answer.
My use case is that I want to send control key and alt key to my shellinabox page from a blackberry phone, which does not have either of those keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old question, but I hope this answer is helpful to someone.

There is a new feature in HTML5, window.postMessage, which allows for communication between an iframe and the hosting window. There's some good documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage).

As usual, you can expect some inconsistencies across browsers: in my experience, Firefox accepts any object as the message, but IE will only accept a string.

There have been some developments to make this feature easy to use in different browsers, including polyfills to make it work in older browsers.

The one that I ended up using was Ben [Alman's jquery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/).

Enjoy!